# How do services like Okta and Auth0 implement their sign-on experience for Azure AD users?

Tags: azure, authentication, oauth, azure-ad-b2c, branding

With Azure AD users, sign-in usually requires you to be redirected to Microsoft URLs to enter your credentials. Okta and Auth0 allow these users to sign in from arbitrary URLs like https://orgname.okta.com/. If you have an Azure AD B2C tenant, is it possible to implement this as well, where your signin is done from a page with your organization's URL and not a Microsoft URL?

Answer (score 1):

Not today, but coming soon. Today you must use contoso.b2clogin.com.

Answer (score -1):

There are two options.

Okta does support a Vanity Login page (you can create a login page using a registered CNAME in DNS. For example **login.company.com** or **sso.company.com**. You can create one Vanity or Hosted login page per Okta instance today.

Or, you can host your login page yourself, and drop the Okta Login widget on the page, and perform the Authentication from your own page.

Here is an example of a self hosted custom login page:

https://super-widget.oktaprise.com/